# I want to create a program that reads data from a text file and print it out in two different sections

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a program that groups the 'names' and 'dates of birth' from a text file, then prints them into two different sections.

1. Data on text file is as follows:

```
Orville Wright 21 July 1988 '\n'
Rogelio Holloway 13 September 1988 '\n'
Marjorie Figueroa 9 October 1988 '\n'
Debra Garner 7 February 1988 '\n'
Tiffany Peters 25 July 1988 '\n'
Hugh Foster 2 June 1988 '\n'
Darren Christensen 21 January 1988 '\n'
Shelia Harrison 28 July 1988 '\n'
Ignacio James 12 September 1988 '\n'
Jerry Keller 30 February 1988 '\n'
Frankie Cobb 1 July 1988 '\n'
Clayton Thomas 10 December 1988 '\n'
Laura Reyes 9 November 1988 '\n'
Danny Jensen 19 September 1988 '\n'
Sabrina Garcia 20 October 1988 '\n'
Winifred Wood 27 July 1988 '\n'
Juan Kennedy 4 March 1988 '\n'
Nina Beck 7 May 1988 '\n'
Tanya Marshall 22 May 1988 '\n'
Kelly Gardner 16 August 1988 '\n'
Cristina Ortega 13 January 1988 '\n'
Guy Carr 21 June 1988 '\n'
Geneva Martinez 5 September 1988 '\n'
Ricardo Howell 23 December 1988 '\n'
Bernadette Rios 19 July 1988][1] '\n'
```

2. The printed format should look something like this. The names are grouped together and the birthdays are grouped together.

```
Name (heading)
1. A Masinga '\n'
Etc. '\n'
Birth date (heading)
1. 21 July 1988 '\n'
Etc. '\n'
```

I'm trying to split the first two words in each line and print them under a heading called "Name" and the last three words in each line and print them under "Birth date". I've tried it in many ways, I can't seem to get it right.

```
name = []
birthday = []
f = open("DOB.txt","r+")
lines = f.readlines()
lines[0:26]
for words in lines:
    if name(lines.split()[:2]): #first two strings are name
        print(name,lines)
    if birthday(words.split()[-3:]): #last three strings are the birthday
        print(birthday)
f.close()
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to print _all_ the names first, then _all_ the birthdays? That's what "_printed format_" looks like. But your current code seems to be printing name and bday alternately.

Comment: Yes Gino, print all names then print all birthdays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code are these:

```
if name(lines.split()[:2])
   ...
if birthday(words.split()[-3:])
   ...
```

`name` and `birthday` are `list`s, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do by calling them as functions (`name()`) and `birthday()`). I think what you were trying to do was *store* the strings into `name` and `birthday`. For that, `list` has an [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method for adding "*an item to the end of the list*".

The other problem is that you were `print`ing the name and bday immediately and alternately inside the loop. You can first store all the names and bdays, then print them all later.

Try this:

```
names = []
bdays = []

f = open("DOB.txt", "r")
data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    parts = line.split()
    names.append(parts[:2])  # store the name
    bdays.append(parts[2:])  # store the bday

f.close()

print("Name")
for i, name in enumerate(names, start=1):
    print("{}. {}".format(i, " ".join(name)))

print("Bday")
for i, bday in enumerate(bdays, start=1):
    print("{}. {}".format(i, " ".join(bday)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance Gino, this was very helpful. I see where I was going wrong.